# New users page - reputation sorting incorrect

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, sorting, users-page

The sorting on the new users page appears to be incorrect - if it goes from left to right then top to bottom (which appears to be the case for most users), then in some cases the sorting is incorrect.

See image:

[image]

Comment: It goes left-to-right, then top-to-bottom. That said, the second row still seems mismatched.

Comment: @Grace The first is too; Mark should be between Erik and alex, not at the end

Comment: @Michael Oh, hey, you're right. That's a 1185, not a 1165.

Comment: @Grace - thanks for correcting me... left to right first, indeed :)

Comment: This sorting method is known as "knight sorting"

Comment: Maybe they just scored some extra rep and bumped their score, but not yet their placings

Comment: @Pekka LOL ... it is actually called "aggressive cache sorting" :) the ordering is cached for 10 minutes, Ill see if I can fudge it so it looks better

Comment: @waffles - problem still there... though I guess it will never get properly fixed, seeing as caching is involved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is by design, as the ordering is cached for 10 minutes, so there may be minor discrepancies if the rep was earned very recently.

Comment: Have you thought about just resorting just that page of answers that is about to be displayed? i.e., pull the page of users out of the cache based on the cached ordering, then just before display sort that page of users.  Or pull a window around the page (say 3 pages worth), resort, and extract the page.  You'd probably still miss some boundary conditions, but the way it is it's more likely to be wrong than right at the top where significant reputation changes are always taking place.