# Curious caching issue on users page

Tags: bug, sorting, users-page, caching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New users page - reputation sorting incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81594/new-users-page-reputation-sorting-incorrect)

A couple of times I've looked over the new users page to find where I am in the weekly/monthly rankings.  A couple of times when I've looked my rep was correct but I appeared out of order in the rankings.  As near as I can tell it's due to recent upvotes which would have moved me up in the ranking.  It's as if my position in the ranking was cached but my score has been updated with the recent votes.  I think you can repeat this if (1) you let your reputation settle for awhile (helps if you don't answer any questions) so that your position gets "cached" then (2) wait until you get a few upvotes -- enough to move you up in the rankings -- and immediately look for your position in the rankings.  You should see that your reputation is updated but you are still behind people with lower reputation over the ranking period.

Comment: Time keeps on tickin' tickin' tickin' into the future...

Comment: This has been asked before (can't find a link right now) and this behaviour is confirmed to be correct. The reps are not cached. The ordering in list is cached for a few minutes.

Comment: Found it: possible duplicate of [New users page - reputation sorting incorrect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81594/new-users-page-reputation-sorting-incorrect)

Comment: @BalusC - I promise that I did look both before creating a question and after typing in the title.