# When sorting on reputation, why are users sub-sorted alphabetically?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, users, sorting, users-page

When sorting users on reputation, users with the same score are sorted alphabetically by their display name. Wouldn't some other sub ordering make more sense?

Incidentally, this also means that names using the Greek and Cyrillic alphabets come after the last Z:

[image: Names using Greek and Cyrillic listed after the last Z]

And after that, display names that are in [Hebrew, Persian, Arabic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9Axu.png), Thai, Japanese, and so on. Eventually, most folks from China and Taiwan are always last:

[image: Last page of users, sorted by reputation]

(I just learned there is also [some caching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81594/new-users-page-reputation-sorting-incorrect) involved, so when browsing the users *a few* names might show on "the wrong" spot given the alphabetic sorting.)

Comment: @Arjan - I think the first logical thing to sub-sort is based on alphabet only. Do you have any other suggestions on this?

Comment: @Sachin, maybe first or last activity, or even the number of visits to the site? (First activity would equal the user id, I guess.)

Comment: @Arjan - +1, fair enough. Seems logical too. Most recent activity ;)

Comment: Well, @Sachin, I'm not claiming it *is* better. I could also imagine that a few users want to know on what page they are? Latest activity might then create confusion too... But I myself was wondered by all the Chinese display names on the last pages.

Comment: Yiddish is kind of a dead language... pretty sure you did not mean that :)

Comment: Hmmm, @Waffles, I didn't even realize that. It is what the automatic language detection of Google Translate gave me...

Comment: @Arjan ... on noes ... Google failed us :) thanks for reporting this bug

Comment: @waffles: Yiddish is [not a dead language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yiddish_language); many people [still enjoy using it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Joys_of_Yiddish).

Comment: @Willie true, but asaf maymon, shlomi elbaz and the joint account for riva and moishy berkovitz are all hebrew, mazganau may be a yiddish though ... who knows

Comment: Yiddish is written in Hebrew script, but is more like German, so you wouldn't easily be able to tell the difference between Hebrew and Yiddish unless you could actually read either one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added a tie breaking subsort on date, most senior account will show up first in case of dupe rep.