# Move flair icon to free up space for display names

Tags: feature-request, flair

The current flair has a site icon to the left of the username, forcing long names to be trimmed. Why not move the icon to the free space below, so there can be more space for the display name?

[image]

(it doesn't *have* to be there; there's plenty of room for it at the bottom).

The [`/about`](https://stackoverflow.com/about) page made me notice this - icons' dis-alignment felt a bit weird.  What it looks like now:

[image: What it looks like now]

What it would look like with the icon repositioned:

[image: Repositioned]

Comment: I actually think that it would be nice for the icon to be placed in the location that you suggest, but made larger (two rows in height) to clearly distinguish the site-specific flair from network flair.

Comment: Shouldn't you also ask for a better rendering of that อ_อ? [Looks bad](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/149052/nulluserexception/flair) to me!

Comment: @Arjan That's what the [original request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/116015/2) had. See the comment thread on Fezziwig's answer to see why I changed it.

Comment: I mean: the *rendering* of that อ_อ is very poor in the flair image. It almost looks like a letter a! So, I'm not referring to the อ_อ being only partly visible. Rendered like that you'd better hide it! ;-)

Comment: @Arjan It isn't *that* terrible.

Comment: Huh? [It's](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair/149052.png) not even close [to this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Nltpk.png)!

Comment: @Arjan It's just a Unicode smiley, it doesn't bother me too much if it doesn't render perfectly.

Comment: Too bad [the sub-sorting of users got fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83537/when-sorting-on-reputation-why-are-users-sub-sorted-alphabetically); it's much harder to find Unicode user names now!

Comment: And feel free to use your ♦ powers to clean up my off-topic stuff! I [won't](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1228/wont/flair) mind ;-)

Comment: @Arjan Won't is a jerk, he moved the Unicode stuff to the *front* of his name, making it impossible for people to use the `@` autocomplete.

Answer (score 5):

This makes it look like network flair where you only have one account:

[image: Network flair]

Maybe you should have a shorter display name? 21 characters is kind of unnecessary -- you're free to have that many if you like, but you shouldn't expect it to fit everywhere. [99.3% of users have display names that will fit](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/121708/); changing the flair design to accommodate the other .7% is a bit silly

Comment: It's also a stylistic thing. I don't see why the icon should be there.

Comment: You know, some people's *real names* are longer than 21 characters. Just sayin'.

Comment: @Chris I'm sure some people's real names are longer than 50 characters too -- should we use 4pt font on flair just in case? If somebody's real name doesn't fit, and they are actually bothered, then I vote for changing it. If we're changing it so NullUserException can fit in his unicode emoticon, then I'm less enthused

Comment: @Fezziwig I agree, making an exception for a Unicode emoticon probably shouldn't be a high priority. I just wanted to point out a slightly more . . . *legitimate* objection to the 21-character limit.

Comment: @Chris OK, I changed my request. Hopefully Michael is happier now.